# Where are d8 options implemented?

Tags: v8

I search for --print-bytecode or --print-ast which are optional arguments of d8 on code search, I cannot find it.
I would like to check all options, but they are not written in the source code. Is my checking method incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

V8 flags are defined in [`src/flags/flag-definition.h`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:v8/src/flags/flag-definitions.h;l=1)¹.

When searching for a flag, you should ignore the initial `--` and replace the remaining dashes (`-`) by underscores (`_`). For instance, if you want to find where `--print-bytecode` is used, search for `print_bytecode`. Additionally, flags are accessed through `v8_flags`, so to be more precise you could search for `v8_flags.print_bytecode`.

Both `print_bytecode` and `print_ast` seem to be only used in `src/interpreter/interpreter.cc`; cf this [search for `print_bytecode`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:v8/src/interpreter/interpreter.cc?q=v8_flags.print_bytecode&ss=chromium%2Fchromium%2Fsrc), and [this one for `print_ast`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:v8/src/interpreter/interpreter.cc?q=v8_flags.print_ast&ss=chromium%2Fchromium%2Fsrc).

Tip 1: when passing flags to d8, you can always use underscores instead of dashes. For instance, `d8 --print_bytecode` and `d8 --print-bytecode` are equivalent.

Tip 2: you can run `d8 --help` to see a list of all available flags.

---

¹ As pointed out by [@jmrk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6036428/jmrk), there are a few d8-specific flags, which are defined in [`src/d8/d8.cc`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:v8/src/d8/d8.cc;l=4844;drc=9fa91fbda95e5db21bd5e3eb3f8c2f5fd4127a1b). These are processed by `Shell::SetOptions`, and are usually used only in `d8.cc`.

Comment: @jmrk Thanks, I added this to the answer :)